# save gui output as it is in a file in computer

Tags: python

I want to save the GUI output of Tkinter window as it is in a file in my local storage device. How can I do that in python?
For example, suppose if we view our result in our college website and when we press download it is saved in a file.So i want exactly the same thing. can anyone help me plz?

Comment: It seems like you want to save the state of your gui. Or do you just want to print the content of your GUI in a nice pdf for say ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you write any code? What exactly do you mean by "output of Tkinter window"? Do you mean a sort of "screenshot" of the window? Also, the example is unclear and does not help illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Plopp - Tq for your response.

Comment: @Plopp - Tq for your response. I guess ur second assumption about my question is correct.  Suppose when i press download button it should  save the output that appeared in tkinter window  as a file in my computer as pdf(say) that i can view later.

Comment: @Plopp Is there any way to do so plz help me out.

Comment: @AlexandruCristiean Just like how we download pdf of a single page that appears on the screen clicking download button same as that i want to save all contents exactly that appeared in tkinter window.

Comment: I cant explain better.Sorry for the trouble.If there was an option to share screenshot ,it would be helpful.